# Lexical analyzer for a programming language

Tags: c, homework

I'm doing a lexical analyzer for my programming language and I don't know if I'm doing it right. Can anyone can help me with this or suggest a better way of doing it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

struct node
{
    char character;
        struct node *link;
}*front = NULL, *rear = NULL;

int isEmpty()
{
        if(front == NULL)
                return 1;
        else
                return 0;
}

char name[4] = "\0";

void enqueue(char character)
{
        struct node *tmp;
        tmp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if(tmp == NULL)
                return;

        tmp -> character = character;
        tmp -> link = NULL;
        if(front == NULL)
        front = tmp;
        else
        rear -> link = tmp;
        rear = tmp;
}

char dequeue()
{
        struct node *tmp;
        char character;
        if(isEmpty())
                return NULL;

        tmp = front;
        character = tmp -> character;
        front = front -> link;
        free(tmp);
        return character;
}

char peek()
{
        if(isEmpty())
                return NULL;
        return front -> character;
}

void display()
{
        struct node *ptr;
        ptr = front;
        if(isEmpty())
                return;

        while(ptr != NULL)
        {
        printf("%c ", ptr -> character);
        ptr = ptr -> link;
        }
}

int issymbol(char c)
{
        char symbols[] = {"!@#$%^&*()_-.?<>,+=-/\\"};

        for(int b = 0; b < strlen(symbols); b++)
                if(c == symbols[b])
                        return 0;
        return 1;
}

int checkIdent(char ident)
{
        if(issymbol(ident))
                return 28;
        else
                return -2;
}

int automaton()
{
        int i = 0;
        char ident[50] = "\0";
        char ch = '\0';
        int next = 0;

        while(1)
        {
                if(peek() == 'c') {
                        ident[i++] = dequeue();
                        if(peek() == 'a') {
                                ident[i++] = dequeue();
                                if(peek() == 's') {
                                        ident[i++] = dequeue();
                                        if(peek() == 'e') {
                                                ident[i++] = dequeue();
                                                if(isalpha(peek()))
                                                        return checkIdent(ch);
                                                else if(isspace(peek()) || peek() == NULL) {
                                                        dequeue();
                                                        return 0;
                                                }
                                        } else
                                                return -1;
                                } else
                                        return -1;
                        } else
                                return -1;
                }

                else if(peek() == 'd') {
                        ident[i++] = dequeue();
                        if(peek() == 'o') {
                                ident[i++] = dequeue();
                                if(isalpha(peek())) {
                                        for(int k = 0; k < next; k++)
                                                name[k] = ident[k];
                                        ch = ident[next + 1];
                                        return checkIdent(ch);
                                }
                                if(isspace(peek()) || peek() == NULL) {
                                        dequeue();
                                        return 1;
                                }
                        } else
                                return -1;
                }

                else if(peek() == 'e') {
                        ident[i++] = dequeue();
                        ch = ident[0];
                        if(peek() == 'l') {
                                ident[i++] = dequeue();
                                if(peek() == 's') {
                                        ident[i++] = dequeue();
                                        if(peek() == 'e') {
                                                ident[i++] = dequeue();
                                                if(isspace(peek())) {
                                                        next = i;
                                                        ident[i++] = dequeue();
                                                        if(peek() == 'i') {
                                                                ident[i++] = dequeue();
                                                                if(peek() == 'f') {
                                                                        ident[i++] = dequeue();
                                                                        if(isalpha(peek())) {
                                                                                for(int k = 0; k < next; k++)
                                                                                        name[k] = ident[k];
                                                                                ch = ident[next + 1];
                                                                                return checkIdent(ch);
                                                                        }
                                                                        if(isspace(peek()) || peek() == NULL) {
                                                                                dequeue();
                                                                                return 3;
                                                                        }
                                                                }
                                                                else {
                                                                        for(int k = 0; k < next; k++)
                                                                                name[k] = ident[k];
                                                                        ch = ident[next + 1];
                                                                        return checkIdent(ch);
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                        else if (isalpha(peek())) {
                                                                for(int k = 0; k < next; k++)
                                                                        name[k] = ident[k];
                                                                ch = ident[next];
                                                                return checkIdent(ch);
                                                        }
                                                        return 2;
                                                } else if(peek() == NULL)
                                                        return 2;
                                                else if(isalpha(peek()))
                                                        return checkIdent(ch);
                                        } else
                                                return -1;
                                } else
                                        return -1;
                        } else
                                return -1;      
                }                

                else            
                        return -1;  
        }                    
}                        

void readSourceCode()    
{                        
        FILE *f = fopen("SAMPLE.nsf","r");
        char c;              

        while((c = getc(f)) != EOF)
                enqueue(c);      

        fclose(f);          
}                        

void main()              
{                        
        clrscr();            
        readSourceCode();              

        while(isEmpty() != 1)
        {
                int i = automaton();
                switch(i)
                {                    
                        case 0: printf("CASE\n"); break;
                        case 1: printf("DO\n"); break;
                        case 2: printf("ELSE\n"); break;
                        case 3: printf("ELSE IF\n"); break;
                        case 28: printf("IDENT\n"); break;
                        default : printf("Invalid! %d", i);
                }

                //printf("%d\n", strlen(name));

                /*if(i == 28 && name[0] != '\0')
                {
                        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++)
                                printf("%c", name[i]);
                }*/
        }
        getch();            
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just C code?  I don't think it should be tagged with [c++].  Also, `main()` should be `int`, not `void`.

Comment: If you're planning on taking this any farther, unless you're doing it for academic pursuit/personal interest/school assignment, I would consider using something like lex to handle the lexing. Custom written lexers tend to get out of hand pretty quickly. Then again, custom ones also have a few advantages.

Comment: @Corbin, yes I'm doing this for my academic pursuit. But we are not allowed to use Lex or any software that generates lexical analyzers.

Comment: I am interested, how much of this was taught to you by your instructor?  Specifically, did your instructor teach you to use `void main()`, compile C code as C++ code, etc.?

Comment: Yes, my instructor in c programming taught us to use void main.. Haha

Comment: @user2745681 Could you join our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) for a bit please?  I have a few more questions to ask about your instructor.

Comment: I have to finish this project before I join..

Comment: @user2745681 I can help you out further in the chat room.  Also, please do not edit in changes to your code, as it invalidates answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Things you could improve:

#### Compilation:

- I am led to believe that you are compiling your code as C++ code.

  > ```
  > tmp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  > ```

  That line right there would be unacceptable when compiling as C code.  And considering that your question originally had [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) on it, I am further convinced that you are compiling your C code as C++ code. **Don't do that**.

  [Here is a *very* long list](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm) of the incompatibilities between ISO C and ISO C++.  Those are the reasons you compile C code, as C code.

  If I happen to be wrong in my assumption that you are compiling C code as C++ code, you still should [not be casting the results of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/1937270).

#### Variables/Initialization:

- You shouldn't use global variables.

  > ```
  > *front = NULL, *rear = NULL;
  > ```

  The problem with global variables is that since every function has access to these, it becomes increasingly hard to figure out which functions actually read and write these variables.

  To understand how the application works, you pretty much have to take into account every function which modifies the global state. That can be done, but as the application grows it will get harder to the point of being virtually impossible (or at least a complete waste of time).

  If you don't rely on global variables, you can pass state around between different functions as needed. That way you stand a much better chance of understanding what each function does, as you don't need to take the global state into account.

  So instead of using global variables, initialize the variables in `main()`, and pass them as arguments to functions if necessary.
- You aren't initializing your arrays properly.

  > ```
  > char name[4] = "\0";
  > ```

  You should be initializing all of your characters in the array at once.

  ```
  char name[4] = {0};
  ```

#### Efficiency:

- You can use the `inline` keyword on some of your functions. The point of making a function `inline` is to hint to the compiler that it is worth making some form of extra effort to call the function faster than it would otherwise - generally by substituting the code of the function into its caller. As well as eliminating the need for a call and return sequence, it might allow the compiler to perform certain optimizations between the bodies of both functions.

  ```
  inline int isEmpty(Node front)
  ```

#### Returns:

- You aren't returning a value from `main()`.

  > ```
  > void main()
  > ```

  You should **always** `return` a value from `main()`.  This is an indication of the status of your program, and whether or not it exited successfully.  This is very important information when it comes to debugging.

  ```
  int main(void)
  {
      ...
      return 0;  // standard return code for successive exit
  }
  ```
- `NULL` isn't a `char`, so you shouldn't treat it as one when you `return` it.

  > ```
  > char peek()
  > {
  >  if(isEmpty())
  >      return NULL;
  >  return front -> character;
  > }
  > ```

  `return` the `NUL`-terminator character instead.

  ```
  return '\0';
  ```

#### Syntax

- `typedef` your `struct`s, and declare and initialize them elsewhere.

  > ```
  > struct node
  > {
  >     char character;
  >         struct node *link;
  > }*front = NULL, *rear = NULL;
  > ```

  The `typedef` means you no longer have to write `struct` all over the place. That not only saves some space, it also can make the code cleaner since it provides a bit more abstraction.

  ```
  typedef struct
  {
      char character;
      struct node *link;
  } Node;
  ```
- You can simplify your `NULL` checks.

  > ```
  >  if(front == NULL)
  > ```

  Since `NULL` is defined as `(void *)0`, we can treat is as a comparison to `0`.

  ```
  if (!front)
  ```
- Use ternary operators when you have simple `if-else` statements.

  > ```
  >  if(front == NULL)
  >      return 1;
  >  else
  >      return 0;
  > }
  > ```

  The [ternary conditional expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?:) is just as simple and verbose as your code, and a whole lot shorter.

  ```
  return (!front) ? 1 : 0;
  ```

  But since we are returning whether this function is true or not, we don't even have a need for the conditional expression at all.

  ```
  return !front;
  ```
- You don't accept any parameters for some of your functions, such as `main()`.  If you do not take in any parameters, declare them as `void`.

  ```
  int main(void)
  ```
- You have a comparison between an `int` and a `void *`.

  > ```
  > peek() == NULL
  > ```

  Compare to `0` instead.

  ```
  0 == peek()
  ```

#### Indentation

- You are very inconsistent with your indenting.

  > ```
  > if(front == NULL)
  > front = tmp;
  > else
  > rear -> link = tmp;
  > rear = tmp;
  > ```

  This isn't very readable.  For one, you don't include braces, which is a whole 'nother debate within itself, but then you don't use indentation.  Please do everyone that is trying to read your code a favor, and indent your code properly.

#### Comments:

- Comments are very important to have in your source code.  Your program has a lack of comments that explain why your code does what it does.  You should add some so you other people can follow your code more easily.
- For the comments you do have...

  > ```
  > //printf("%d\n", strlen(name));
  >
  > /*if(i == 28 && name[0] != '\0')
  >  {
  >  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++)
  >  printf("%c", name[i]);
  >  }*/
  > ```

  Remove them.  Commented out code is really just useless clutter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have any idea how can I improve my function automaton() ??

Comment: @user2745681 I'm still working on reviewing the code. :)

Comment: @syb0rg If you really wanted to simplify the `if/else` redundancy, you could just do `return !front` instead of the ternary conditional :)

Comment: Does casting the result of `malloc()` really make it an invalid C program? The answers in the Stack Overflow question that you linked to don't even agree unanimously that casting is a bad idea. (Anyway, there are plenty of issues with the code that are more urgent than the `malloc()` cast.)

Comment: @200_success: It remains valid C code (i.e., barring other problems, a C compiler should accept the code). It's generally agreed that it's a bad idea in C though.

Answer (score 10):

I think you're overcomplicating the problem by working a character at a time.

- Reading one character at a time using `getc()` is inefficient.  You could fetch a bigger chunk at a time using `fread()`.
- Wrapping each character into a linked list node is wasteful.  While each character normally takes one byte when stored in a large array or a string, your linked list node is likely to take more than eight bytes.  On a 32-bit system, a `struct node` will probably use one byte for the character itself, four bytes for a pointer, and three wasted bytes in between to allow the pointer to be aligned at an address that is a multiple of four.  On a 64-bit system, it would be even worse.  Also, `malloc()` incurs some memory overhead for its bookkeeping (so that it remembers the size of the chunk of memory that will be liberated when `free()` is eventually called).
- Analyzing the text one character at a time is tedious.  That's some of the deepest indentation I've seen in any code.  If you keep the data as a string, you could use some string handling routines from the standard C library, such as `strsep()`.

#### Suggestion

I'll try to provide some guidance without giving away a complete solution to your [homework](/questions/tagged/homework).

The key insight is that it is possible to construct an automaton that works at a higher level than character-by-character.

I'll start with `main()`.

```
/* Advice: The C standard says that main() must return an int, not void. */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* Advice: Don't hard-code input filename.  Accept a command-line parameter instead */
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s FILENAME\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    const char *filename = argv[1];

    /* Advice: Avoid global variables. Return a pointer instead. */
    char *program = readSourceCode(filename);
    if (!program) {
        perror(filename);
        return 1;
    }

    const char *cursor = program;
    while (*cursor) {
        /* Advice: What does your automaton do?  Pick an informative name. */
        switch (consumeKeyword(&cursor)) {
          /* Advice: Avoid magic numbers.  #define constants or use an enum. */
          case CASE:    printf("CASE\n"); break;
          case DO:      printf("DO\n"); break;
          case ELSE:    printf("ELSE\n"); break;
          case ELSEIF:  printf("ELSE IF\n"); break;
          default:
            if (isIdentifier(&cursor)) {
                printf("IDENT\n"); break;
            } else {
                printf("Invalid! %s", cursor);
            }
            free(program);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    free(program);
    return 0;
}
```

The first thing to get out of the way is `readSourceCode()`.  See if you can implement this:

```
/**
 * Returns the contents of the specified file as a NUL-terminated string.
 * If any error occurs (e.g. file not found, permission denied, no free memory),
 * returns NULL, and errno will tell the reason.
 */
char *readSourceCode(const char *filename) {
    /* Hints: Use stat() or fstat() to find the file size.
       Allocate that many bytes, plus 1 for the '\0'.
       Remember to fclose() when done!
     */
    …
}
```

The main challenge is `consumeKeyword()`.  As you can see, `main()` passes a "cursor" to `consumeKeyword()` — it does so by reference, so that `consumeKeyword()` can increment main's cursor.

```
enum keyword {
    NOT_A_KEYWORD,
    …
};

/**
 * Skips over any whitespace characters at the cursor, then looks for any
 * recognizable keywords.  If a keyword is found, advances the cursor to
 * just beyond the end of the keyword.  If no keyword is found, returns
 * NOT_A_KEYWORD and leaves the cursor in place.
 */
enum keyword consumeKeyword(const char **cursor) {
    while (isspace(**cursor)) {
        (*cursor)++;
    }
    size_t advance;
    if ((advance = isKeyword(cursor, "case"))) {
        *cursor += advance;
        return CASE;
    } else if … {
        …
    } else {
        return NOT_A_KEYWORD;
    }
}
```

You should be able to fill in the rest:

```
/**
 * If the specified keyword is found at the specified cursor position,
 * returns the length of the keyword.  Otherwise, returns 0.
 */
size_t isKeyword(const char *const *cursor, const char *keyword) {
    /* Hint: With a for-loop, the entire function should take no more
       than four lines. */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have any idea how can I improve my function automaton() ??

Comment: Your `main()` is not too far off, but I suggest rewriting everything else based on the outline I've added above.

Answer (score 10):

Right now, I think your `automaton` has an awful lot of code to just recognize 4 key words. A typical lexer will read an entire (potential) token, then compare it to a table of key words to see if it matches any of them.

For example, let's assume a token must always consist of a letter followed by an arbitrary number of letters and/or digits. That's pretty easy to encode:

```
void read_ident(char *id, size_t max) { 
    unsigned pos = 0;
    if (isalpha(peek())) 
        while (isalnum(ch=getnext())&&pos < MAX)
            id[pos++] = ch;
    id[pos] = '\0';
}
```

Using this (or something similar) code to read some key words would end up quite a bit simpler:

```
static char const *table[] = {
    "case",
    "do",
    "else",
    "if"
};

#define elements(table) (sizeof(table)/sizeof(table[0]))
char buffer[256];

read_ident(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
for (i=0; i<elements(table); i++)
    if (0 == strcmp(buffer, table[i])
        return i;
// none of them matched
return 28;
```

Note that (at least for the moment) I've had it recognize "if", rather than "else if", as a keyword. I'd recognize `else if` as two key words: an `else` followed by an `if`, rather than as a single key word (that happens to include a space). That's not the only way to do things, but it's generally simpler.

For the moment, I've had it do a simple linear search through the table to find a (possible) keyword. Given the small number of key words you've given, that makes sense. If you had to deal with more key words, you might want to switch to a sorted table so you could use a binary search, or else to a hash table. If the 28 you used as a magic number elsewhere indicates you actually have 27 key words to recognize, a sorted table might improve speed a little, but a hash table is *probably* overkill.

That brings us to one other point: returning "magic" numbers for the key words (0, 1, 2, 3, 28). You normally want to use an `enum` (or series of `#define`s) to give logical names to these instead of using the raw numbers directly:

```
 enum { INVALID = -1, T_DO, T_CASE, T_IF, T_ELSE, T_ID};
```

Then the code that uses it can look a little more meaningful, like:

```
switch (token) { 
    T_DO:           printf("do\n");       break;
    T_CASE:         printf("case\n");     break;
    T_IF:           printf("if\n");       break;
    T_ELSE:         printf("else\n");     break;
    T_ID:           printf("ID\n");       break;
    T_INVALID:
    default:        printf("Invalid\n");  break;
}
```

Another possibility to consider (since you can make these contiguous and starting from 0) is to use them as an index into an array instead:

```
if (token >= 0 && token <= T_LAST)
    printf("%s\n", table[token]);
```

Note that for this, you can (and usually want to) re-use the same table you used to find keywords when tokenizing.

Answer (score 6):

## Approach

I would use arrays rather than an unnecessary linked list structure. In particular, have an array of the contents with an index into it (or pointer) and an array of your current token. This way you avoid the expensive overhead of allocating and deallocating all of the time, and you get cache locality. From a theoretical point of view, operating on characters is fine, but from a practical point of view, it's incredibly inefficient.

---

Rather than doing character by character scanning, I would try to use more general rules and then back track to check for correctness. For example, you can keep scanning forward as long as you have an alphabetic character. Then, you can check the token to make sure it's an acceptable token. A very crude example of this:

```
char* contents = ...;
char* content_ptr = ...;

char* token = ...;
char* token_ptr = token;

memset(token, 0, token_size);

while (isalpha(*content_ptr)) {
    *token++ = *content_ptr++;
}

if (is_valid_token(token)) {
    // do something with the token
} else {
    // Parse error!
}
```

So, if you had "while cake" your code would parse through the token "while", see that it's valid, store it somehow, and then continue on (the code to skip over non-tokens is not included in my example, but you could likely get away with just eating white space). When getting to "cake", you could go ahead and capture the entire thing, and only when you've captured the entire token see that it's a non-sense token and spit out an error. This way simplifies your processing since it allows you to think at a token level rather than an atom level.

---

Really, if you're planning on continuing this much farther, I would consider using something like lex. You can just give it a set of rules, and it will build an automaton for you. DFAs are quite cumbersome to build by hand and if you decide to change rules, they get even more difficult to work with. By working at a rule level, you get to avoid that clutter. You can even pair lex with something like bison to create a full parser rather than just a lexer.

---

## Technicalities

There are a few things wrong with your code from a technical point of view. A good place to start is compiling with a modern compiler with the warnings turned on and thinking long and hard if the warnings are worth ignoring (hint: they almost never are).

A lot of things have been covered by others, so I will only post what I believe no one else has mentioned yet.

---

```
char peek()
{
        if(isEmpty())
                return NULL;
        return front -> character;
}
```

`NULL` is not a valid value for a `char`. Yes, it's technically allowed, but it's a very bad idea. NULL is a possible value for a pointer, not a character. It would be like `int x = 'a';`. Yes, it's technically possible, but it's nonsensical. If you want NULL-like sentinel for a character, you can use a null character (`0`, or `'\0'`).

---

When possible, avoid non-standard parts of C. In particular, `conio.h` is going to tie you to very specific environments (in particular, Windows with either Turbo C compiler or Microsoft's Visual Studio's C compiler). `clrscr` is probably not worth tying yourself to windows over. In fact, I would consider this program clearing my terminal to be annoying. Let the terminal handle its own rendering.

---

What if reading the file fails? readSourceCode() gives no indication of success or failure. Also, if the fopen call fails, the read on the is likely going to cause a segfault. You need to check error conditions more carefully.

---

Globals have very, very few legitimate uses. Get out of the habit of using them as quickly as you can.

---

Anytime you hard code a string like a file name, ask yourself if it should be a parameter instead. Instead of `readSourceCode` having the file path hard coded, it should be parameter.

---

Actually, the filepath shouldn't be a parameter. A function should never create a resource it uses based on it's inputs. Rather than a filepath, you would want to pass readSourceCode a `FILE*`. That way it has one less responsibility in that it no longer has to handle opening/closing the file. It only has to handle reading it (look up single responsibility principle).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Corbin! But our professor told that we have to use a Finite Automaton for it.

Comment: @user2745681 Ah, ok :)